# Is "Edit like below" is correct?

Tags: determiners, writing

I want to write in my blog `edit like below`.

**Example -**

> You will make edit like below -
>
> `One` to `Tow`

Is correct?

Comment: ELL isn't a proofreading site. You'll have to identify specific concerns, rather than ask about general correctness. Why do you think it is (or isn't) correct? What material made you think this? etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It could do with some repair :-)

First, "make edit" would need to be "make an edit". I don't know what the precise rule is, but while you can "make amends", "make love", or "make sense", you must "make a mess", "make a fool (of yourself)" and of course "make an edit". So that gets us started by changing the original from:

> You will make edit like below:

to:

> You will make **an** edit like below:

Then although there's perhaps nothing strictly wrong with "like below", it would be more common to say "as follows", as follows (see what I just did there :-) ) :

> You will make an edit **as follows**:

I would also change "will" to "would" (and again :-) ). In general, "You *will* " suggests that the thing is more or less inevitable. That is contrasted with "You *would* ", which is more conditional -- that is, it means that the thing will happen only if some other conditions are met. In your context, a condition could be simply that the person must actually want to achieve whatever it is you are explaining to them. So:

> You **would** make an edit as follows:

You could stop here. The above would be fine to use as-is.

But you could go further still, depending on your precise intent. So it might be better to say "could" instead of "would":

> You **could** make an edit as follows:

So now, as well as being conditional, your advice is also a little less prescriptive. That is, you're making it clear that you're merely giving an *example* of how to achieve the end result but that there may well be other ways of doing it. However whether that's appropriate depends, as I say, on your precise intent, so let's leave it as "would" for the time being.

Going further still--and now I'm reading as if I'm correcting a student paper, so reasonable minds may certainly differ on this--I'll note that your phrase:

> `One` to `Tow`

is not actually an edit at all. Rather, it is describing the *result* of an edit. It is what you would want your reader to *produce using an edit*. Given that, it might be better to say:

> You would **make edits so as to change** `One` to `Tow`

Or you could change your example so that it *is* an edit after all, thereby leaving the first part as it was. Perhaps something like this:

> You would make the following edit:
>
> **s/One/Tow**

But then you could tinker even more. By giving that precise edit command, I've now made the already somewhat prescriptive "would" form even more prescriptive. So I might want to soften that back down again by using the "could" I mentioned earlier. So:

> You **could** make the following edit:
>
> s/One/Tow

But that's getting into sheer word-smithing and personal preference so your mileage may vary.

Finally, my brain is compelling me to note that instead of:

> `One` to `Tow`

I assume you actually meant:

> `One` to **Two**

But of course that is completely irrelevant to your question context. It's just that I'm now in Professor-marking-a-paper-mode and I'll not be able to sleep at night unless I comment on even the tiniest potential error :-D

Comment: No problem. I see you're new to SE, so a suggestion: I see you've already "accepted" my answer and so it usually makes sense to also vote it up. That said, I'd suggest waiting a little time before deciding on which answer to "accept" (you can only choose one). By accepting too quickly you may discourage others from answering, and there could be (probably are!) better answers than mine out there! So feel free to "un-accept" mine. You can always re-accept it later if you want. And you can vote up (or down) independently of accepting.

Comment: I see it was upvoted in the time it took me to comment. If that was you, fair enough. But my suggestion about waiting still stands. What's sometimes weird is finding a question where the most popular answer is not actually the accepted one. That's actually fine, since accepted just means accepted *by the original poster*. But in practice it often means that one got accepted early and then later on an even better one arrived. But either way the accepted one always gets listed first, which always strikes me as being wrong (I'd rather the most popular was at the top). But anyway, I waffle.